# Segfault on specifying string in struct field to use in other functions

Tags: c

I have declared the following struct. In the second function, I am declaring a struct of that type and then try and fill in the string name field. However, if I try to access this field in other functions, it is giving me a seg-fault. Is everything declared correctly, or does it require a malloc? Also, other fields in this struct appear to be stored properly, except the string name.

```
typedef struct {
unsigned int   name;                        // offset into string table for symbol name
uintptr_t      addr;                    // symbol address
unsigned int   size;                        // symbol size in bytes 
} Symbol;

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    unsigned int address;
    int size;
    char binding;
} PrintedSymbol;
```

One of the functions creates a struct like this:

```
PrintedSymbol* create_symbols(char *string_data, Symbol *symbols) {

    Symbol symbol;
    int count = 0;

    int size = 22;
    PrintedSymbol *arr = malloc(sizeof(PrintedSymbol) * size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        PrintedSymbol unique;
        symbol = symbols[i];

        char *str_location = (char *) string_data + symbol.name;
        char *str_name = strdup(str_location);
        unique.name = str_name;

        arr[count] = unique;
        count++;

    }

    Array printthis;
    printthis.arr = arr;
    printthis.count = count;

    return printthis;
}
```

EDIT: I have also edited the function above - note, I still have not malloced as I am storing it in a struct.

I am trying to print the name by doing the following:

I have stored the array along with its count in another struct like this:
typedef struct {
   PrintedSymbol *arr;
   int count
} Array

This is now what the function PrintedSymbol is returning to plug into this function:

```
   void output_symbols(Array printthis, char *hex, char *string_data, Symbol *symbols) {

    // set-up variables from struct
    PrintedSymbol *arr = printthis.arr;
    int count = printthis.count;

    if (hex == NULL) {
            print_symbol_table(arr, count); <-- THIS FUNCTION IS PRINTING OUT THE ARRAY PROPERLY

    } else {

            PrintedSymbol key;
            qsort(arr, count, sizeof(key), lex_sort);
            key.address = strtol(hex, NULL, 16);
            key.size = 1;
            size_t symbol_size = sizeof(key);

            void *matching = lfind(&key, arr, &symbol_size, count, compare_address);
            unsigned int hex_int = strtol(hex, NULL, 16);

            if (matching != NULL) {

                    PrintedSymbol matched = *(PrintedSymbol *) matching; 
                    printf("%d and %s\n", hex_int, matched.name, matched.size); <-- printing the SIZE is fine, the NAME gives a segfault!

            } 
    }
```

When I print with the malloc in, it gives me this:

```
 00000029 and (Ps
 0000000d and �Oh
 00000014 and �Oh
 00000012 and main
 00000014 and P_
 00000015 and P)
```

The messed up characters are where the strings should be, everything else is fine. Lfind is the standard C lfind function, I have not defined it.

Printing the size of the symbol being returned by lfind is fine, but not the name, which is giving a seg-fault. Why?

Comment: Where is the variable `symbol` declared?

Comment: Does your `create_symbols` even compile? you're returning what appears to be a local variable, but what's more: `arr` is never once declared. Voting to close, on the basis that this reeks of a _"Why isn't this code working/debug this for me"_ question

Comment: Sorry - that wasn't the problem - edited now.

Comment: `string_data + symbol.name` you're adding two `char *`s.

Comment: `char *str_location = (char *) string_data + symbol.name;` : use `malloc`, `strcpy`, `strcat`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY OP uses `strdup` later on, so that's not the issue

Comment: What is the type of `PrintingArray`? If it's `PrintingSymbol *` then you're returning a pointer to stack data. But either way, this should be closed because of the missing code to allow anyone else to recreate your issue.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen I have pointed out the problem with the concatenation of CString.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen symbol.name is not a char*, because symbol is of struct Symbol and the name field is of type int.

Comment: The symbol struct has been added for a closer look.

Comment: One issue: in `create_symbols` you return a pointer to a locally declared variable (`arr`). Once you have returned from the function, that variable has gone out of scope and is no longer valid and you will get indefined behaviour.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks. However, I do seem to be able to access all the other fields of array. Why would unique.name or the name field be the only field affected?

Comment: @user3844996: undefined behaviour. Undefined behaviour means: anything can happen. it might crash the first time, it might never crash, it might corrupt some data somewhere which will lead to crashes later, it might work 99 time and crash on the 100th time etc.

Comment: @MichaelWalz So what change is needed to make it work? I am a bit unsure as to why returning a pointer to the array won't work? Should I malloc the array?

Comment: @user3844996: yes you should malloc it. As I wrote before: local variables are allocated on the stack, and once you leave the function they are no longer valid, because memory location where these variables are stored will be overwritten sooner or later. google _local variables stack c_ and you will find plenty of information. Also search the same thing on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Michael Walz said in a comment: you allocate the array on the stack. After you return, it passes out of scope and the memory associated with it gets overwritten. You need to change this:

```
PrintedSymbol arr[size];
```

to:

```
PrintedSymbol* arr = malloc(sizeof(PrintedSymbol) * size);
```

Apart from that, you're not doing any bounds checking here:

```
char *str_location = (char *) string_data + symbol.name;
```

and something will go wrong if `symbol.name` puts you outside of `string_data`.

EDIT: You've made a mistake with your types. `Symbol` has a member named `name`, but its an `int`, not a `char*`. So when you try to print it, it interprets the bytes it finds as a `char*` and gives you garbage.

You probably meant:

```
PrintedSymbol matched = *(PrintedSymbol*) matching;
```

EDIT EDIT: `lfind` has the following signature:

```
 void*  lfind ( const void * key, const void * base, size_t num, size_t width, int (*fncomparison)(const void *, const void * ) );
```

When you call:

```
 lfind(&key, arr, &symbol_size, count, compare_address);
```

and pass `&symbol_size` as a parameter, it gets a very large value for `num`. It also looks like you've reversed `num` and `width`. This is probably causing unexpected behavior. You probably meant:

```
 lfind(&key, arr, count, symbol_size, compare_address);
```

You should turn on `-Wall`, because gcc will warn you if you try to pass in a `size_t*` where the function is expecting a `size_t`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, when I malloc the array, I get garbage being printed out for the string when it is passed to any other function, even though I can print str_name on the inside and it is being stored properly.

Comment: @user3844996 Can you post an example of where you're getting this garbage printed, and how you're printing it? My guess is that the error is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I have added it as an edit above. Thanks very much for taking the time.

Comment: @user3844996 It doesn't matter if you've saved it in a `struct`, you still need to `malloc` the memory for it. The `struct` just holds a pointer to the array, if the array is on the stack, it still passes out of scope and gets trashed. Go back and make the original change I suggested and it should work.

Comment: It doesn't, unfortunately. It just prints out garbage.

Comment: @user3844996 Also post `lfind`, the issue is likely there.

Comment: Added now - as I have said, the lfind is the standard C lfind. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3844996 `PrintedSymbol* create_symbols` is a typo, right? You return an `Array` from this function.

Comment: Looking at it now, do you think it could be because strdup does not null terminate functions? Does strdup automatically null-terminate?

Comment: @user3844996 It copies the original string [up to the `NUL`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html). So if your original string was `NUL`-terminated, this one should be too. If that were the problem, I'd expect to see a very long string of garbage, since it would run off the end of what it should and in to other memory.

Comment: That doesn't fix it either.

Comment: @user3844996 You have lines like `Symbol *arr = printthis.arr;` -- you don't ever want this, the type here is `PrintedSymbol*` not `Symbol*`. Fix all of those and post the full updated code. Also turn on `-Wall` in your compiler and see if GCC tells you anything useful.

Comment: I've tried to fix everything now, apologies - there was just a lot to post, etc. The weird thing is if I print out str_name in create_symbols from the struct, it is fine. All the other fields are fine as well when printed out in functions - just the strings are messed up.

Comment: Finally, if I run this program in GDB, the strings are being printed perfectly.

Comment: @user3844996 I've posted a fix to another problem in your code, but that really points towards a memory error somewhere. If at all possible, you should run it under `valgrind` and see what it says.

Comment: I honestly can't thank you enough - all works now. StackOverflow can be a pretty iffy place and you really had no reason to stick it out, but I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The address of a local variable in a function depends on the state of the stack (the value of the SP register) at the point in execution when the function is called.

In other words, this address is not the same every time the function is called.

Therefore, returning the address of a local variable leads to undefined behavior.

With `return arr`, you are essentially returning the address of `arr` in memory.

Note that with arrays (unlike other types of variables) there is no such thing as "value".

For example:

```
int  var;    // mostly var != &var
int* ptr;    // mostly ptr != &ptr
int  arr[4]; // always arr == &arr
```

So while you could safely return `var` or `ptr` after initializing them properly, you may not do so with `arr`.